# Applying purrr::map2 on two columns of nested tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr

This questions concerns operation in the language of `tidyverse`. I am trying to use `tidyr::nest` and `purrr:map2` to perform a bivariate function on two columns of a `tibble`, replacing them with two other columns which are the result of that bivariate function. The operation is that of computing ROC based on values of the statistic under `H0` and `H1` which produces two new values (i.e. columns) `FPR` and `TPR`. Here is a working example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(purrr)
# function to compute the rejection rates
get_reject_freq <- function(Tstat, th_vec, twosided=T) {
  # Tstat is a vector, th could be a vector of thresholds threshold
  if (twosided) Tstat <- abs(Tstat)
  sapply(th_vec, function(th) mean(Tstat > th))
}

# function to compute the ROC
get_ROC <- function(T0, T1, twosided=T) {
  T0_sorted <- sort(unique(T0), decreasing = T)
  tibble(FPR = get_reject_freq(T0, T0_sorted, twosided = twosided), 
         TPR = get_reject_freq(T1, T0_sorted, twosided = twosided))
}

n = m = 15
run_sims_one_iter <- function(j) {
  x = rt(n, df=5, ncp=0)
  y = list(H0=rt(m, df=5, ncp=0), H1=rt(m, df=5, ncp=1))

  result = NULL
  for (h in c("H0","H1")) {
    result[[h]] = tibble(method="t_test", H=h, 
                         test_stat=t.test(x,y[[h]])$statistic) %>% 
      add_row(method="wilcoxon", H=h, 
              test_stat=wilcox.test(x,y[[h]], alternative = "two.sided")$statistic, )
  }
  return( bind_rows(result) )
}

result = bind_rows( lapply(1:100, run_sims_one_iter) )


#### The following can hopefully be improved ###
temp = result %>% 
  group_by(method,H) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = H, values_from = data) %>%
  ungroup()


roc_results = bind_rows( 
  lapply(1:nrow(temp), function(i) {
    get_ROC( temp[[i,"H0"]]$test_stat, temp[[i,"H1"]]$test_stat) %>% 
      add_column(method = temp[i,]$method)
  }
))
```

The line

```
temp = result %>% 
  group_by(method,H) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = H, values_from = data) %>%
  ungroup()
```

produces an output of the form:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
  method   H0                 H1                
  <chr>    <list>             <list>            
1 t_test   <tibble [100 × 1]> <tibble [100 × 1]>
2 wilcoxon <tibble [100 × 1]> <tibble [100 × 1]>
```

The code should operate on each row taking the two tibbles in `H0` and `H1` columns, passing them through the `get_ROC` function and replacing them with `FPR` and `TPR` columns and then `unnest` everything. The desired `roc_result` generated by the above code is

```
 roc_results
# A tibble: 157 x 3
     FPR   TPR method
   <dbl> <dbl> <chr> 
 1  0.03  0.76 t_test
 2  0.04  0.77 t_test
 3  0.07  0.82 t_test
...
```

Ideally, I would like to replace the construction of `temp` and `roc_results` with a single line of the form:

```
temp = result %>% 
  group_by(method,H) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = H, values_from = data) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(res=map2(unlist(H0), unlist(H1), get_ROC)) %>% unnest(res)
```

But this doesn't work. I guess the issue might be that the size of the output of `get_ROC` could change for every row (?). Any idea how I can perform all the operations using the `tidyverse` approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were in the right direction but you had to `unlist` in the function of `map2` instead of in the arguments.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

result %>% 
  group_by(method,H) %>% 
  nest() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = H, values_from = data) %>% 
  mutate(res = purrr::map2(H0, H1, ~get_ROC(unlist(.x), unlist(.y)))) %>%
  unnest(res) %>%
  select(-c(H0, H1))

#  method   FPR   TPR
#   <chr>  <dbl> <dbl>
# 1 t_test  0.01  0.49
# 2 t_test  0.06  0.59
# 3 t_test  0.08  0.65
# 4 t_test  0.1   0.74
# 5 t_test  0.11  0.77
# 6 t_test  0.13  0.82
# 7 t_test  0.19  0.84
# 8 t_test  0.21  0.84
# 9 t_test  0.22  0.85
#10 t_test  0.24  0.86
# … with 156 more rows
```

Comment: Great! Do you have a pointer to the documentation regarding the use of `(.x)` notation here? It would also help if there is an explanation of the use of `~` . Any explanation of why your version works while the other doesn't is also appreciated.

Comment: @passerby51 yes, `~` is a formula-style syntax to apply a function. It is an alternative to an anonymous function. You can refer  `?map`.

Comment: OK, thanks. So it is an issue with `purrr`'s map function? I still can't understand why the original version that I have doesn't work.

Comment: Nope...it has nothing to do with `map`. See the difference of output in `unlist(temp$H0)` and `unlist(temp$H0[1])`. What you are doing is the former one whereas what you need is later one. You are unlisting list of dataframe whereas my answer unlists only a dataframe.